# LDAP not loading into php 5.6 on RHL 7

Tags: php, codeigniter, ldap, redhat

I'm having some issues connecting to an LDAP server using PHP 5.6 on a RHL 7 environment. The application itself is running Codeigniter, and when I attempt an LDAP connection I get the error:

> LDAP functionality not present. Either load the module ldap php module
>   or use a php with ldap support compiled in.

I've used yum to install PHP-ldap and openldap, as well as manually added the extension in the loaded PHP.ini file with.

```
extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/ldap.so
```

However, I'm still getting the error, and phpinfo () is not showing ldap as a loaded module.

I've also checked my Apache error logs for anything useful in there. While I'm getting no errors when I attempt to reload the page, when I restart the server, I am getting an error:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib64/php/modules/ldap.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/ldap.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown
>   on line 0

I have checked, and ldap.so does exist at that location.

I should also mention that PHP is installed at an abnormal location, it's at `/opt/rh/rh-php56`, not sure if that might be causing the issue.

UPDATE: -----------
I've copied and moved ldap.so to `/opt/rh/rh-php56/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/ldap.so` and removed the path in php.ini so that it now calls ldap like `extension=ldap.so`.

The warning has changed to

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: ldap: Unable to initialize module\nModule
>   compiled with module API=20100525\nPHP    compiled with module
>   API=20131226\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0

Is there something I need to do to compile the ldap.so file?

Comment: you sure that the so is really there, and it's not (say) a broken symlink?

Comment: Yep, it's showing up as -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   57792 Apr  4 07:15 ldap.so

Answer (score 0):

The issue came down to installing the wrong version of LDAP for the version of PHP the server was running.

As I am running rh-php56-php, I also needed to install rh-php56-php-ldap, not the standard php-ldap package. Once the correct package was installed, the errors that I was encountering ceased.